# Functional Equation: $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)+f(y)~~~\forall x, y>0$

Tags: functional-equations

So I have the question:

$$f(x\cdot y)=f(x)+f(y)~~~\forall x, y>0$$

We haven't learn these in class and I'm assuming it has a logarithmic answer.
Could anyone please help?

Comment: Hi Jose, thank you very much for the formatting! Sorry I didn't make an attempt because this is far outside the maths that I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Regarding not making an attempt - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, we discover that you have 5 choices,

> [...]  This is a mutli choice with the 5 options being: $x, 2^x, \log(x)/\log(5), \sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

So you can check that there's only one of these that works.

- $x$ doesn't work: $1=1\times 1 \neq 1+1=2$
- $2^x$ doesn't work: $1=2^{0\times0} \neq 2^0 + 2^0=2$
- $\sin x$ doesn't work: $\sin((\pi/2)^2)<1$ but $\sin(\pi/2)+\sin(\pi/2)=2>1$
- $\cos x$ doesn't work: $\cos(0\times 0)=1\neq \cos(0)+\cos(0) = 2$

The $\log$ one, you can check does work, using the properties of logs you learned in class. Or, if you trust that there is one correct answer, we are done.

Comment: Oh so you can literally check to see if it is true or false by doing that. Thank you very much for this! Definitely has opened my eyes to a new side of maths with all the complex calculations going on. I'll get there one day but thank you!

Comment: @XB Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer the question properly because I used $x=y=0$ in some cases but the question specifically states $x,y>0$. However, the idea of testing specific cases still works, and I invite you to find counterexamples that truly work for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(e^{x})$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. [Because $g(x+y)=f(e^{x+y})=f(e^{x}e^{y})=f(e^{x})+f(e^{y})=g(x)+g(y)$]. There are many 'bad' solutions but the only continuous functions satisfying this equation are of the form $g(x)=cx$ where $c$ is a constant. So $f(x)=c\, log \,x$ if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: it should be $\ln x$.

Comment: Stupid mistake! Thanks @Szeto for pointing out.

Comment: @Kavi Notice that the equation is $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: Yes, that is the equation I have considered in my answer.

Comment: No, you say $g(x+y)$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I'm a year 11 student and I don't think we do these at all in our high school education and I'm really struggling to grapple this idea. This is a mutli choice with the 5 options being: x, 2^x, log(x)/log(5), sin(x) and cos(x). So the answer would either be the exponential or the log I'm guessing?

Comment: @Dog_69 I have added an extra step to the proof. Please take a look.

Comment: OK. I see the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Functional equations are solved using methods such as @Kavi has presented in his anwer. Here I there is another approach for this problem using algebra.

The exponential function is a group homomorphism of $(\mathbb R,+)$ into $(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$. furthermore, we can restrict ourselves to the subgroup of positive numbers of $\mathbb R^*$ and then $e^{cx}$ becomes a group isomorphism, $c>0$. Then, there exists an inverse function $f(x)$ that is also a group isomorphism of $(\mathbb R^+,\cdot)$ onto $(\mathbb R,+)$. The $f$ is the function we are looking for. A simple computation shoes that $f(x)=\frac{1}{c}\log(x)$.

**Remark.** As it has been discussed in the comments, I have obtained a family of solutions for the functional equation focus on a particular group homomorphisms (isomorphism). Moreover, it corresponds to the unique family of continuous functions. But there are more functions satisfying the functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. They also are group homomorphisms of $(\mathbb R^+,\cdot)$ into $(\mathbb R,+)$ but its expression can be very difficult.

Comment: In this language, where have you discarded the 'wild' solutions that aren't continuous?

Comment: @Dog_69 You cannot answer this question with pure algebra. it is well known that there are lots non-measurable functions satisfying the given functional equation

Comment: @Calvin I haven't discarded any solution. I claim that the exponential map is a group isomorphism and then that the inverse function is too and satisfies the desired equation.

Comment: @Kavi But it was not my intention to discard them. ''My solution'' provides a family of solutions. But I'm not claiming it is the unique family of solutions.

Comment: Ah, so the other solutions correspond to other group homomorphisms. thanks (I was thrown off when you said "the $f$ is `the` function we are looking for")

Comment: @Calvin Maybe it was't well expressed. I'm going to add a remark highlighting that my solution is not unique.